# How to replace a xml tag with DTD entity

Tags: xml, dtd, liquibase

I can replace a xml Attribute values using DTD Entity declaration using following methode

```
//in DTD
<!ENTITY varchar "VARCHAR(200)">
// In xml 
<column name="attachment_url" type="&varchar;"/>
```

Now I want to replace a xml tag like

`<column name="attachment_url" type="VARCHAR(200)"/>`

using DTD Entity.

I try like 
`<!ENTITY full_coulumn "&lt;column name=&quot;attachment_url&quot; type=&quot;VARCHAR(200)&quot;/&gt;">`

then i get an error

```
 Unexpected column with text: <column name="attachment_url" type="VARCHAR(200)
"/>
```

Is it possible to replace entire xml tag with dtd Entity? How can i do that?

I am try to do this with liquibase xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't escape the markup in the entity declaration; by doing so, you signal to the processor that the entity's replacement text is a string of characters, not markup.  What you want is:

```
<!ENTITY full_column "<column name='attachment_url' 
                      type='VARCHAR(200)' />">
```

Comment: can i replace the xml attribute with entity tag? Eg: in <createTable tableName="communication"> i want to replce tableName="communication" part with an entity.Is it possible? I try like <!ENTITY communication "tableName='communication'">  But it  shows an error Element type "createTable" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" o r "/>".

Comment: No; XML entity references are recognized within attribute values (so you can write `<createTable tableName="&tbl-name;"/>` or the equivalent), and within content, but not within start-tags generally.