# Liquibase - common columns?

Tags: java, liquibase

In my db every table has 4 common columns - `DATE_CREATED`, `USER_CREATED`, `DATE_MODIFIED`, `USER_MODIFIED`, and I want to propagate this rule to all new tables implicitly.

Is it possible to do it without having to generate liquibase script manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define in Liquibase a set of default columns, def. PKs, def. indexes, def. values for table creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228076/how-to-define-in-liquibase-a-set-of-default-columns-def-pks-def-indexes-def)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using liquibase (as far as I know).

The reason for this is simple:

What if you change your mind and add/remove one of the default columns later? If you want to change all tables then this is not possible with liquibase as this would mean changing all changesets, which is not allowed.

Use a DSL to generate your liquibase scripts then you can add a certain set of columns to every entity but an automatic way would be difficult with the way liquibase works.

Comment: This approach suits better in my case. I'm thinking of DSL that will generate new changelog xml files and register them in changelog index file.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built into Liquibase to support this.

Your easiest option would be to use XML document entities which is purely XML-level and therefore transparent to Liquibase. They would allow you to attach common XML into your changelog files.

A more complex approach would be to use the Liquibase extension system (http://liquibase.org/extensions) which allows you to redefine the logic to convert changeSets into SQL. That would allow you to inject any logic you want, including common data types, standard columns, or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think so.

My suggesion, Dont add above mentioned 4 columns in all tables because there are possible to keep null values in all table for existing entries.

please create a table like Primary key id, table or entity name and your four column name.